# How can I match a regex in a switch statement?

Tags: java, regex, switch-statement

I'm trying to match tokens against a switch statement in a function, and one of those tokens needs to be able to identify *any* string or *any* numbers defined by the regex in the code below.

Basically, is it possible to define a regex against a case like `case "[a-z]+":`

Clearly the way I have it now, my pattern is not reachable unless I pass `STRING` or `NUMBER` as an argument.

```
public Token analyzeToken(String token) {
      Token tokenType = null;     

      switch (token) {

         case "STRING":
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(token);
            if(m.matches()) {
               tokenType = Token.STRING;
               break;
            }
         case "NUMBER":
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(token);
            if(m.matches()) {
               tokenType = Token.NUMBER;
               break;

         case "(":
            tokenType = Token.LEFT_PAREN;
            break;
         case ")":
            tokenType = Token.RIGHT_PAREN;
            break;
         case ".":
            tokenType = Token.PERIOD;
            break;
         case ":":
            tokenType = Token.COLON;
            break;
         case ";":
            tokenType = Token.SEMICOLON;

         default:
            tokenType = TOKEN.UNKNOWN;
            break;

      }
   }
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: In my case statement I have "STRING" and "NUMBER" but that's not going to be the token passed to the function.  So what do I define with `case`?

Comment: This looks like a http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: This could work in Java8, there you can switch on String literals

Comment: @Gavriel I'm trying to match against any string.  Is this possible with a switch statement?

Comment: You just did it. Look at your `default`. Either you don't understand how switch works, or you don't know what you really want to achieve. Maybe show us possible inputs. What token can be?

Comment: @Gavriel I modified it with more details.  Also have a look at my regex, I'm looking for specific strings containing only letters or strings containing only numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure why what I'm saying is coming across so confusing, but `case "STRING":` is not going to work, I put `"STRING"` there just as a placeholder to describe what I want the switch to match on.  I want to basically do `case "MY_REGEX":`

Comment: Basically, the answer is no.  The only language I know of that lets you "switch" on regexes is Perl.  Maybe there are others.

Comment: @ajb thanks for the info.

Comment: actually, now that I'm looking into it further, I'm not sure Perl actually has a `switch` like that, although you can fake it pretty easily.  I may have been thinking of one of the Unix shells.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do it in a `switch` statement, do it in a conditional or better yet, in a loop:

```
private interface TokenMatcher {
    Token match(String s);
}
static List<TokenMatcher> matchers = new ArrayList<>();
static {
    final Pattern strPattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+");
    final Pattern numPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
    matchers.add( new TokenMatcher {
        public Token match(String s) {
            Matcher m = strPattern.matcher(s);
            return m.matches() ? Token.STRING : null;
        }
    });
    matchers.add( new TokenMatcher {
        public Token match(String s) {
            Matcher m = numPattern.matcher(s);
            return m.matches() ? Token.NUMBER : null;
        }
    });
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
static Token match(String s) {
    for (TokenMatcher m : matchers) {
        Token t = m.match(s);
        if (t != null) {
            return t;
        }
    }
    return TOKEN.UNKNOWN;
}
```

The `for` loop has taken place of the `switch` statement, while the entries in the `matchers` list have taken place of the individual `case`s in the `switch`. Adding new token types is as simple as adding new patterns and their associated implementations to the `matchers` list.

**Edit:** You could make the solution shorter by replacing the interface above with a class, like this:

```
private static final class TokenMatcher {
    private final Pattern p;
    private final Token t;
    public TokenMatcher(String pString, Token t) {
        p = Pattern.compile(pString);
        this.t = t;
    }
    public Token match(String s) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        return m.matches() ? t: null;
    }
}
```

Now your `matchers` initialization could be done like this:

```
matchers.add(new TokenMatcher("[a-z]+", Token.STRING));
matchers.add(new TokenMatcher("[0-9]+", Token.NUMBER));
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for!  Thank you.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, nice solution, but don't you think it will be better to have a `Map` where key is `String` pattern and value is `Token`? Then in match method you can just iterate patterns. And less repeated code.

Comment: @KenBekov Map does not give you much advantage in this situation, because you never look up by pattern. Essentially, to your program it becomes a list of `(Pattern, Token)` tuples. Setting up a class instead of an interface, on the other hand, would give you less repeated code. Please see the edit.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, our solutions are totally equal (not surprising, be cause mine is based on yours). There is just one difference: I store patterns as `String`, and you store patterns as instance of `Pattern` class. In my code just one instance of `Pattern`, which will be released after `match` method is done.

Comment: @KenBekov Storing a string forces you to compile the pattern each time you go through a loop, though, which is something I'm trying to avoid when it is possible.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, agree. If pattern will be more complicated, it's better to store it pre-compiled. Anyway it is a usual choice between the memory and performance.

Answer (score 2):

This solution inspired by solution of *@dasblinkenlight*.
Just attempt to improve it.

```
public class TokenMatcher{

    private HashMap<String, Token> tokenMap = new HashMap<String, Token>();
    {
        tokenMap.put("[a-z]+", Token.STRING);
        tokenMap.put("[0-9]+", Token.NUMBER);
        tokenMap.put("\\(", Token.RIGHT_PARENT);
        tokenMap.put("\\)", Token.LEFT_PARENT);
        ...
    }


    public Token match(String s){
        for(String key : tokenMap.keySet()){
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(key);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
            if(matcher.matches()) return tokenMap.get(key);
        }
        return Token.UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Improvements: easier to add new token, less repeated code, don't need extra interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need 2 parameters:

```
public Token analyzeToken(String token, String string) {
      Token tokenType = null;     
      switch (token) {
         case "STRING":
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(string); // match the string, not the token!
            if(m.matches()) {
               tokenType = Token.STRING;
               break;
            }
```

update:

```
public Token analyzeToken(String regex, String string) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(string); // match the string, not the token!
            if(m.matches()) {
               // ...
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will not be the best solution for you, but in general you can pass regex to switch statement as enum. This is good only if you do not need to create regular expressions dynamically.

```
enum PatternCase {
    pattern1("regexp1"),
    pattern2("regexp2"),
    pattern3("regexp3"),
    pattern4("regexp4", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
    ;
    final Pattern pattern;
    PatternCase(String regExp) { pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp); }
    PatternCase(String regExp, int flags) { pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp, flags); }
}
```

Then you have fully working switch with regular expression as its case statement.

```
        Matcher matcher = null;
        PatternCase matchedPatternCase = null;  // Or use some default value to avoid null checks.

        // Match only these patterns and match them in this effective order.
        for (PatternCase patternCase : new PatternCase[]{ PatternCase.pattern3, PatternCase.pattern1 }) {
            matcher = patternCase.pattern.matcher(text);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                matchedPatternCase = patternCase;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (matchedPatternCase != null) switch (matchedPatternCase) {
            case pattern1:
                System.out.println(matcher.group());
                break;
            case pattern3:
                do { System.out.println(matcher.group()); } while (matcher.find());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

If your Token value is enum already, it may (or may not) be appropriate to use Pattern directly in your Token enum and simply iterate over all Token enum values.